# Delete all scores of an application via Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just start using the API in trying to deal with scores in a game.

I am able :

- to **GET** my personal score with **USER_ID/scores**,
- to **GET** all the scores of an application using **APP_ID/scores**,
- to **DELETE** my personal score using **USER_ID/scores**

Curiously, I am not able to delete all the scores of my application.

As I checked the documentation, I tried using **DELETE** method on **APP_ID/scores** but it definitely returns **"error": "Request failed"**

However, I made an "all access" token.
The documentation does not tell something special about this kind of deletion.

Comment: Reading the docs: “You can delete the current score for a user for your app by issuing an `HTTP DELETE` request to `/USER_ID/scores` with a user or app `access_token` as long as your app has the `publish_actions` permission.” Do you have the `public_actions` permission?

Comment: Yep, in order to make tests easily, I made an `access_token` with all the permissions, including `publish_actions`.